# How to upload a Zip File using Octokit?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, octokit.net

How to upload a zip file using Octokit.net? I am new to Octokit.net  anyone could you possible provide code snippet?

Comment: This is not the `OctoKit` help and support page, i suggest studying the documentation and if you have a concrete problem then come back and see us and we will be more than happy to help. Please read this [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ocktokit.net docs are quite complete, read the [docs](https://octokitnet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/) well.

This is an example from the docs:

```
var client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("my-cool-app"));
var basicAuth = new Credentials("username", "password"); // NOTE: not real credentials
client.Credentials = basicAuth;

using(var archiveContents = File.OpenRead("output.zip")) { // TODO: better sample
    var assetUpload = new ReleaseAssetUpload() 
    {
         FileName = "my-cool-project-1.0.zip",
         ContentType = "application/zip",
         RawData = archiveContents
    };
    var release = client.Repository.Release.Get("octokit", "octokit.net", 1);
    var asset = await client.Repository.Release.UploadAsset(release, assetUpload);
}
```